# Intershop CartBO field for the total before taxes

Tags: intershop

Unfortunately you can not query the docs by field terms such as `TotalNetPrice`.  The field I'm looking for is `total before taxes` which would include all line items except the sales tax, like so:

line items,

shipping,

promos,

## etc.

Per [Willem Evertse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6148442/willem-evertse)  **getGrandTotalNet** is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the total Net price with discounts then u can use this method on the BasketBO:

```
Money getGrandTotalNet()
Gets the total net price.
Returns:
the total net price
```

Comment: Does that include shipping charges too?

Comment: I see now that it doesn't. So my answer is wrong. You should have getGrandTotalNet i suppose. This should include everything excluding the tax. If you also want to exclude gift cards from the total, then you have to use getBasketTotalPriceMinusLimitedTenderNet.